# Optimized solution for merging list items

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

I have an array of content blocks like so:

```
interface Content{
  type: string,
  content: string | string[]
}
const content: Content[] = [
  {
    type: "heading"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "para"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "para"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "list_item"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "list_item"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "list_item"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "para"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "heading"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "para"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "para"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "list_item"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "list_item"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "list_item"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "list_item"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "para"
    content: "whatever"
  },
]
```

I'm trying to write a function which can merge these `list_item`'s into a `list` with an array for the content of each. So, the output of the function for the above input should be:

```
[
  {
    type: "heading"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "para"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "para"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "list"
    content: ["whatever","whatever","whatever"]
  },
  {
    type: "para"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "heading"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "para"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "para"
    content: "whatever"
  },
  {
    type: "list"
    content: ["whatever", "whatever", "whatever", "whatever"]
  },
  {
    type: "para"
    content: "whatever"
  },
]
```

I've been trying to use a three-pointer system, looping over the array from i=1 to i < length - 1, tracking the `prev`, `curr` and `next` blocks, however, I am getting very stuck with the logic and how I should handle the cases.

I feel like this is quite a simple problem for more experienced algorithm designers, so, I was looking for some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly straightforward loop, checking if the `current.type` is a 'list_item' and either instantiating a new object with `type: 'list'` or pushing to the previous object if we've already created one.

```js
const content = [{ type: "heading", content: "whatever" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list1 1" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list1 2" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list1 3" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "heading", content: "whatever" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list2 1" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list2 2" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list2 3" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list2 4" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" },];

const res = [];
for (const item of content) {
  if (item.type === 'list_item') {
    if (res[res.length - 1]?.type !== 'list') {
      res.push({ type: 'list', content: [] });
    }
    res[res.length - 1].content.push(item.content);
  } else {
    res.push({ ...item });
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

An alternative that avoids having to repeatedly access the tail of the array is to store a reference to the active list array in a temp variable and reset it every time a sequence of `list_item`s ends. ([TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKZQKYJgXhgbQN4ygTwAdEAuGAIgAtEBDAEwEswBzMgGjnCQVLIHcLqSAG6IATmRgBfdjnxEeBaqOpsOCZFB79BiEeKkzchEuUXLV8LpvLbhYidJizjPADb1oAfXpIAthc4NNw8oAEYYUIdDORMydy8fRH92SyDyeLCYACYopyN5dJDvPwD1bkLocIBmXOcCsjMVFMDyvgE7fUc62Ko6RhZmsus2nT1a-NjG0qstdt17AzyYhSUmtRmbObHF7uCEksGNuJCsiPHliqhipOm04+hTnJ2JvavE5PW7jNOa54v7t4HT6tb4wAAs5xcplWt1atnmnVYAF0ANwAKDR8GgMFEiAgaEwqLRrkQsD8BAJGCJADMQKIYAAKLGwd4wEDU4FQACUTjRMBg9A5DPeADoYmhUOgAOQZa6+KU8rB8-kCoUAQnJIpJzCgFEVypVOLxIoIAFcIBQGbsYDKQlLDmlyVIuejDZIDbgkgQTebLaLUggXcrJDBEK4IIheYbBYzNdqmLr9Yb+U70FTXSr3YbcRAfRarTARUXWZIg-z3e7MeAICASVqQEwGTmg0A))

```js
const content = [{ type: "heading", content: "whatever" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list1 1" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list1 2" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list1 3" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "heading", content: "whatever" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list2 1" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list2 2" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list2 3" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list2 4" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" },];

const res = [];
let temp = [];
for (const item of content) {
  if (item.type === 'list_item') {
    if (!temp.length) {
      res.push({ type: 'list', content: temp });
    }
    temp.push(item.content);
  } else {
    if (temp.length) {
      temp = [];
    }
    res.push({ ...item });
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` to return the new array:

```js
const content = [{ type: "heading", content: "whatever" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list1 1" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list1 2" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list1 3" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "heading", content: "whatever" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list2 1" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list2 2" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list2 3" }, { type: "list_item", content: "list2 4" }, { type: "para", content: "whatever" },];

const result = content.reduce(function (acc, item) {
    if (item.type !== "list_item") {
        acc.push({...item });
    } else if (acc.at(-1)?.type !== 'list') {
        acc.push({ type: 'list', content: [item.content] });
    } else {
        acc.at(-1).content.push(item.content);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

`at(-1)` is used to retrieve the last entry in the accumulating array, and `?.` is used so not to fail when the accumulating array is still empty.

Answer (score -1):

I think just use js builtin array method is optimized enough

```js
const a = [
      {
        type: "heading",
        content: "whatever"
      },
      {
        type: "para",
        content: "whatever"
      },
      {
        type: "para",
        content: "whatever"
      },
      {
        type: "list_item",
        content: "whatever 1"
      },
      {
        type: "list_item",
        content: "whatever 2"
      },
      {
        type: "list_item",
        content: "whatever 3"
      },
      {
        type: "para",
        content: "whatever"
      },
      {
        type: "heading",
        content: "whatever"
      },
      {
        type: "para",
        content: "whatever"
      },
      {
        type: "para",
        content: "whatever"
      },
      {
        type: "list_item",
        content: "whatever 4"
      },
      {
        type: "list_item",
        content: "whatever 5"
      },
      {
        type: "list_item",
        content: "whatever 6"
      },
      {
        type: "list_item",
        content: "whatever 7"
      },
      {
        type: "para",
        content: "whatever"
      },
    ]
    let listItemContent = [];
    const res = a.reduce((total, v) => {
      if(v.type === "list_item") {
        listItemContent.push(v.content);
      }
      else if(listItemContent.length > 0) {
        total.push({type: "list", content: listItemContent});
        listItemContent = [];
      } else {
        total.push(v);
      }
      return total;
    }, []);
    if(listItemContent.length > 0) {
      res.push({type: "list", content: listItemContent});
    }
    console.log(res)
```

Comment: This puts all the list items into one list, but only consecutive list_items should be added.

Comment: my bad, you are right, i've edited code snippet

Comment: Unfortunately your new example skips elements right after the last `list_item` of a sequence, and also doesn't capture lists whose last 'list_item' is at the end of the array.